# OpenVPN "breaks" my local DNS down

Tags: networking, dns, openvpn, dhcp, isc-dhcpd

> Context:
>
> - Router-computer (Ubuntu 14) runs a wifi AP (wlan0), as a router between clients and Internet (on eth0).
> - For DHCP it uses `isc-dhcp-server` and DNS resolvers are defined in `dhcpd.conf` (it uses Google DNS 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4).
> - Finally, allows bi ip forwarding eth0<=>wlan0.

**Problem**

If OpenVPN is launched, after or before I launch the wifi AP. 
**It breaks my DNS...** . Actually, DNS seems to stop working: clients domain request all fail (error DNS resolve). Please note that my openvpn dns config uses also Google DNS 8888/8844.

How can I solve this to use OpenVPN with my WifiAP ?